# QuickSort implementation lower equals

Tags: algorithm, quicksort

I looked over quickSort implementation and I've seen that all the websites have this definition:

```
private void quickSort(int [] array, int low, int high) {         
    int i = low; int j = high;
    int pivot = array[low+(high-low)/2];
    while (i <= j) {
        while (array[i] < pivot) { i++; }
        while (array[j] > pivot) { j--; }
        if (i <= j) {
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i]=arr[j];
            arr[j]=temp;
            i++; j--;
        }
    }
    if (low < j) quickSort(array, low, j);
    if (i < high) quickSort(array, i, high);
}
```

I want to ask you about **while(i <= j)**, why can't it be just **while(i < j)**, because it compares the same array element, I made some tests and it works without equals. Giving the fact that all the implementations are the same, it has to have a meaning there, but I don't know which the valid case is.

Comment: why do you strongly believe above while(i<=j) is correct? just wondering whether you got the source from might have a flaw.

Comment: the first three sources I've found have this check i<=j, so I supposed this is the correct way of implementing it..

Answer (score 0):

I would start by pointing a bug in your code you are trying to switch the array elements in a non existing array (i guess just a wrong copy paste). see my fixed code below.

To answer your question, the code will eventually get to the right sorted array but it will run a couple of unnecessary iterations when it gets to the point where i = j. 
i.e. if the original array list was `{24,2,1,31,45}` with the `while(i<=j)` it will run through quickSort recursively only 3 times :

The output would be:

```
[24, 2, 1, 31, 45]
[1, 2, 24, 31, 45]
[1, 2, 24, 31, 45]
```

As when running it with `while(i<j)` it will run 4 times recursively :

```
[24, 2, 1, 31, 45]
[1, 2, 24, 31, 45]
[1, 2, 24, 31, 45]
[1, 2, 24, 31, 45]
```

The 3rd time was unnecessary and the only reason it ran again was because i = j and instead of shifting both cursors to the next element it just called the method recursively again with the same low and high values.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class HisQuickSort {

private void quickSort(int [] array, int low, int high) {

    int i = low; int j = high;
    int pivot = array[low+(high-low)/2];
    while (i <= j) {
        while (array[i] < pivot) { i++; }
        while (array[j] > pivot) { j--; }
        if (i <= j) {
            int temp = array[i];
            array[i]=array[j];
            array[j]=temp;
            i++; j--;
        }
    }
    if (low < j) quickSort(array, low, j);
    if (i < high) quickSort(array, i, high);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

}

public static void main(String a[]){

    HisQuickSort sorter = new HisQuickSort();
    //int[] array2 = new int[1000];
    //array2 = randomizeArray(array2);
    int[] input = {24,2,1,45,31};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(input));

    sorter.quickSort(input, 0, input.length-1);

}
}
```